# How to get VarImp plot for glmnet to display variable importance in both directions?

Tags: r, glmnet

I have the product of cross-validated regression, with the object being of class train; it used 'glmnet' as the method.

```
objModel <- train(trainDF[,predictorsNames], trainDF[,outcomeName], 
              method='glmnet',  metric = "RMSE", trControl=objControl)
plot(varImp(objModel,scale=F))
```

When I plot the variable importance using VarImp, it accurately shows the importance of the variables, but it indicates them all in the positive direction. For instance, I know that 'lib' and 'cohort:Millenial' are negative predictors, but of high magnitude. 
[image]

Every walkthrough and aid I have seen/used automatically plots the variables importance in the proper direction with plot(VarImp), with negative importance variables going left on the x-axis from the origin and positive importance variables going right from the origin; however, all of the variables are plotted as positive importance. Proper magnitude, but wrong direction.

Is there an in-depth fix for this problem? The documentation for VarImp remarks that glmnet objects get assigned importance based on the absolute value of the t-statistic, but that doesn't explain why I see the code run properly in depicting negative importance elsewhere. Thanks so much.

Comment: "Importance" is a metric. A metric is nonnegative by definition. If you want _signed_ importance, that's something else.

Comment: That is correct. For reference I am talking about 20:55 in the following demo. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nai4NBx5zI